# Windows Vista x64 freezes randomly

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, freeze, dell-xps

my computer (a Dell XPS M1330 - Vista x64) hangs randomly. When it happens I can't run the task manager (or another app), nor the Start menu, and when i try to close an application the title bar shows "Not responding".

In the event viewers, nothing particular, excepts the hard shutdown.

**Update**

I've got the following BSOD lately: [alt text http://pix.zancdar.eu/s/x5sc](http://pix.zancdar.eu/s/x5sc)

(I apologize in advance for my bad english..)

Answer (score 1):

It could be a hardware fault so I'd start by running a memory test tool like [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) to check if you have some faulty memory.

Comment: The RAM isn't faulty. But i've got a BSOD with the 0x00000024 error code (caused by ntfs.sys (and pshed.dll)).

Comment: Could still be one of many other hardware faults (power supply, cpu, cooling, motherboard) or a corrupt file system.